# In a CFD simulation the wingtip vortexes gets reduced/cancelled by means of Wingtip End Plates- if this is true is it then useful?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing-tip-vortex

I am just working on a special kind of wing and I do named it a Transformer Wing.
The transformation is about the wing camber.
The main requirement of the project is that the wing is to be not flexible but be able to reverse the camber within a second.
The choosen specific solution requires that the transformer wings need to be short, rectangular and effective.

Check the idea of my wing on YouTube:

As the wing needs to be short and rectangular then the wingtip vortex will destroy much of the lift produced by the wing due to very low AR.
Therefore my work gets much to be concentrated to understand the wingtip tornado vortex.
As the wing needs to reverse the camber it was not possible to apply any of the existing, well working solutions within aviation, except for End Plates.
It is to be noted that the Wingtips End Plate form used for my wing are dividing the air flow into four smaller vortexes.
The very low pressure caused by the wingtip vortexes is now moved toward leading edge
therefore the lift vector is directed as we do want.
It is possible that we can still improve the form of the end plate in order to prohibit observed turbulence close to trailing edge.
It looks that the End Plates can be compact and add not much to wing span or wingtip weight.
At the same time they are nice-looking and are effective when it comes to aerodynamics.
Right now I find that proposed End Plates improved the CL and L/D (Ok, its only CFD).

**Now to my question:**
**My observation is that the vortexes can cancel each other to some degree** as they rotate in same rotational direction (i.e. both are rotating clockwise on the left edge of the wing span) though when they meet then the air speed goes down.
**This phenomenon might reduce the dirty air behind sailing vessels and reduce danger for aeroplanes?**

Comment: Can you post a couple of pictures from your CFD simulation?

Comment: Interesting concept, what would be the purpose?

Comment: For end plates to be beneficial, the savings in induced drag must outweigh the increase in parasite drag from end plates themselves; possible if the end plates have a thin aerofoil. Also, the savings in induced drag depends on the net induced drag itself, so the end plates might improve the aerodynamics at high Cl (low speeds), but worsen it at low Cl (high speeds).